# error when using better player in flutter

Tags: flutter

E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel: Failed to handle method call
java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior.
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:174)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource$Factory.setDrmSessionManagerProvider(ProgressiveMediaSource.java:186)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.buildMediaSource(BetterPlayer.kt:430)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.setDataSource(BetterPlayer.kt:196)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.setDataSource(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:277)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:151)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:138)
at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior., null, java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior.
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:174)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource$Factory.setDrmSessionManagerProvider(ProgressiveMediaSource.java:186)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.buildMediaSource(BetterPlayer.kt:430)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.setDataSource(BetterPlayer.kt:196)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.setDataSource(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:277)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:151)
at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:138)
at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18)

#2      MethodChannelVideoPlayer.setDataSource (package:better_player/src/video_player/method_channel_video_player.dart:118:5)

#3      VideoPlayerController._setDataSource (package:better_player/src/video_player/video_player.dart:408:5)

#4      BetterPlayerController._setupDataSource (package:better_player/src/core/better_player_controller.dart:444:9)

#5      BetterPlayerController.setupDataSource (package:better_player/src/core/better_player_controller.dart:274:5)

```
I face this problem when I use better_player in flutter, It was work good but now show this problem .
Any one can help me
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck